# How to select from unknown number of databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to show a customer a history of their total orders across multiple 'vendors'. Each vendor has a separate database in SQL server to store their own orders.

In my database I only know which vendors the user is signed up with. So my sequence needs to go like this:

1. Get all the VendorIDs that the user is signed up with.
2. Go to the Vendor table and get their server + database name
3. Perform a select statement that gets all orders from each Order table in each of the Vendor databases that the user is signed up to.

> ```
> DECLARE @UserID int = 999
>
> SELECT Count(OrderNumber) AS 'Orders'
>
> FROM
> --- Need some kind of loop here?
> [VendorServer].[VendorDB].[OrderTable] o1
>
> WHERE 
> o1.UserID = @UserID
> ```

How would I get the aggregate of the total number of orders this customer made when their orders are spread across multiple databases?

The User may be signed up to over 100 vendors. So it has to query across 100 databases. This is an extreme example but its possible.

Comment: Does any server (something like master server) that hold a reference (something like LinkedServer) to all the vendor servers?

Comment: @Rex Not yet. At the moment I'm in development so all the Vendor databases are sitting on the same server. I just thought that in the future the Vendors may want to host their own DB themselves so I have to anticipate needing to connect to their server to get the data. For this solution I'm happy to ignore the Server aspect. I just can't get my head around how to show a total figure across multiple databases.

Comment: If you plan to do that, you then eventually need to have a centralized server somewhere to serve as a master to reference to all the vendor servers via LinkedServer, and then you could use dynamic sql (build the sql query on the fly) to query them in 'one' go. let me know if you need a sample

Comment: Yes I have a centralised server/db which acts as the master. It contains tables that holds data on all the Vendor databases. I would like to query each vendor database but then aggregate them into a total. Is that possible? A sample would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved using dynamic query: the query itself is generated dynamically and then executed.

Without the table schema it's impossible to write something that will work in your environment but the idea will be

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @query += 'UNION ALL 
                  SELECT whatever 
                  FROM   ' + VendorServer + '.' + VendorDB + '.OrdeTable
                  WHERE  condition'
FROM   Vendor
WHERE  VendorID IN (all the VendorIDs that the user is signed up with) 

SET @query = SUBSTRING(@query, 10, LEN(@query))

EXEC sp_executesql(@query)
```

---

The OP in a comment described this schema

```
CREATE TABLE User_Vendor (
  UserID int
, VendorID int
)

CREATE TABLE Vendors (
  VendorID int
, Name varchar(50)
, DatabaseName varchar(50)
, Servername varchar(50)
)
```

in that case the query/stored procedure body will be

```
DECLARE @UserID int = '999'
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

DECLARE @vUserID nvarchar(10) = CAST(UserID as nvarchar(10))

SELECT @query += 'UNION ALL 
                  SELECT Count(OrderNumber) AS [Orders]
                  FROM   ' + v.Servername + '.' + v.DatabaseName + '.OrdeTable
                  WHERE  o1.UserID = ' + @UserID + ' '
FROM   User_Vendor uv
       INNER JOIN Vendors v ON uv.VendorID = v.VendorID
WHERE  uv.UserID = @UserID

SET @query = SUBSTRING(@query, 10, LEN(@query))

EXEC sp_executesql(@query)
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/40a18/7)</kbd> with a `SELECT @query` instead of the `EXEC sp_executesql(@query)`

the added variable `@vUserID` is to avoid multiple `CAST` in the query, the `User` table is not needed in the query.

To get the total figure of the orders, instead of the count for every vendor, the line

```
SET @query = SUBSTRING(@query, 10, LEN(@query))
```

should be changed to

```
SET @query = 'SELECT SUM([Orders]) [Orders]
              FROM (' + SUBSTRING(@query, 10, LEN(@query)) + ') a'
```

Comment: oh Union All. totally forgot about that.

Comment: I'll have to put a big loop around the whole code right? Because the User may be signed up to any number of vendors e.g. 100 vendors

Comment: If the information about the link between the user and the vendor is in a table there is no need of a loop, just join that table too, if you can disclose the table schema I'll edit the query :)

Comment: The table that connects Users to a Vendors is `dbo.User_Vendor` which has columns `UserID, VendorID`. There is then a table called dbo.Vendors which tells everything about a vendor. The columns are like `VendorID, Name, DatabaseName, Servername`. So I just join between the `User`, `User_Vendor`, and `Vendor` table to get details on what databases to query.

Answer (score 1):

though similar to Serpiton's answer, just post for your reference -

```
    DECLARE @userId INT;
    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

    SELECT  @sql += ' SELECT COUNT(*) Cnt FROM ' + 
                    ServerName + '.' + DbName + '.' + tblNameWithSchema + 
                    ' WHERE UserId = ' + CAST(@userId AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' UNION ALL '
    FROM    yourTbl
    WHERE   UserId = @userId;

    -- Remove excessive 'Union All'
    SET @sql = SUBSTRING(@sql, LEN(@sql) - LEN(' UNION ALL '), LEN(' UNION ALL '));

    SET @sql = 'SELECT SUM(Cnt) FROM (' + @sql + ') tmp'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql(@sql);
```